# How to enable column reordering in SlickGird via drag/drop?

Tags: slickgrid

I've seen it done in the samples, but can't get it to work on my Grid.

What do I need to do in order to allow drag/drop column reordering in SlickGrid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create the grid, you should be doing something like:

```
grid = new Slick.Grid($("#myGrid"), data, columns, options);
```

options is a dictionary that you can use to change the behavior of the slickgrid. Make sure that the enableColumnReorder key is set to true:

```
var options = {
  enableColumnReorder: true
};
```

If this does not work, please do post your code so we can take a look.

Comment: I get 
'Error: SlickGrid's "enableColumnReorder = true" option requires jquery-ui.sortable module to be loaded' 

But I don't see this module in the Source code, I'm using 2.0a

Comment: "Got it, Thanks"... Can you explain how?

Answer (score 1):

Answering the comments above (@hiphip) - slickgrid comes with a bundled compatible version of jquery-ui. You need to add this as a script tag to you page e.g.

```
<script src="/slickgrid/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```