# How to disable slickgrid column reordering after being enabled?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I was expecting a simple `grid.setOptions({enableColumnReorder:false})` to disable the column reordering after it is enabled, but that doesnt seem to work. I've tried to invalidate the grid as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a duplicate. Also, the correct answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540642/how-to-enable-column-reordering-in-slickgird-via-drag-drop

Answer (score 2):

Also render the grid...depends on how you have written the code..

```
grid.setOptions({
  enableColumnReorder:false
});
grid.invalidate();
grid.render();
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work, actually I think invalidate calls render eventually.